# Exclude specific IP with port from a iptable rule having range of ip and port

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Need help to create an iptable rule which will redirect all request of ip range 172.16.0.1 to 172.16.0.120 with port range 20-8081 to localhost service listening on port 22215, but this rule should not catch ip 172.16.0.111 with port 443 (i.e., 172.16.0.111:443 should directly access through internet).

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:22215
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j ACCEPT
```

After applying the above rule all the request which has ip and port in the above range are redirected to 127.0.0.1:22215. But I am not getting how to exclude ip 172.16.0.111 having port 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall rules are processed from top to bottom. Place specific rules on top, and generic rules (catch-all rules) at the bottom. What ever you want to do with `172.16.0.111:443`, its rule must go on top (before the three rules you posted)

```
iptables -I INPUT --src 172.16.0.111 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT --src 172.16.0.111 ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:22215
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:8081 -m iprange --dst-range 172.16.0.1-172.16.0.120 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Note: You might want to tighten rule #2 by providing source or destination port number.